# How to create variable subscriptions in Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using stripe to capture credit cards. I have my forms so that they are variable inputs, and it works great. I am passing the information from my `<input>` to a charge.php file and it captures successfully.

When I try to use this information to create subscriptions, I am unable to use variable amounts. I can only create a subscription that has a set amount.

I was hoping to use the `$finalamount` to set the amount of the subscription.
I am okay with the  `name` and `id` to be the same as the `amount`.

How can I create a variable subscription including custom `amount`, `name`, and `id` based on what the user inputs?

```
<?php

require_once('init.php');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_***********");

// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$email = $_POST['stripeEmail'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$finalamount = $amount * 100;

\Stripe\Plan::create(array(
  "amount" => $finalamount, //this does not work. It only works if there is a present amount. 
  "interval" => "month",
  "name" => "Green Plan",
  "currency" => "usd",
  "id" => "green")
);

// Create a Customer
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  "source" => $token,
  "plan" => "green",
  "description" => "Description",
  "email" => $email)
);


// Charge the Customer instead of the card
\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => $finalamount, // amount in cents, again
  "currency" => "usd",
  "customer" => $customer->id)
);

?>
```

Comment: what is the error you get when you try your code?

Comment: I don't get an error, it just doesn't process. It only processes when there is a set amount.

Comment: you should enable PHP error logging. By default this is disabled and it will just stop processing. So doesn't process = an error that just isn't displayed to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this code

```
\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => $finalamount, // amount in cents, again
  "currency" => "usd",
  "customer" => $customer->id)
);
```

because when you create a customer specifying plan your customer is subscribed and charged automatically.

hope it helps :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the note. Unfortunately, removing that line didn't help me in processing the Subscription. The subscription did post, which is nice. But it removes the `email` for some reason, and there is still no `amount`. I would think the `$finalamount` would set this, but it isn't for some reason.

Comment: I would suggest you log the $finalamount, email to check if they have any values or not. please show me any errors you are receiving. I might be able to help you beacuse i myself have implemented similar functionality in a project.