# How to do a variable amount recurent donation plan subscription with Stripe JS PHP

Tags: javascript, php, variables, stripe-payments, subscription

I'm not a crazy coder expert but i would like to use the Stripe lightbox form with these features:

- User can enter variable amount for One shot donation then charge him 
  (it's look to work, i can see the token and charge in Stripe)
- User can enter variable amount for Annual Donation then charge him then send a email receipe, the minimum amount is 3000 YEN (around 30$)

The problem :

- In the form i use a technic to make the user to pay minimum 3000 YEN if he change the value to 0 for exemple when he focus out the input area in become 3000 again that's why i use value="3000" but it will be nicer if it can be only 
  placeholder="3,000 YEN Minimum"
- After charge user Stripe doesn't send email confirmation, i read it doesnt do it in test mode, still true ?
- I would like to hide the public key from html source if it's possible
- The main problem is when user enter a variable amount and validate the form it launch the Stripe lightbox windows then it launch the charge2.php on my server but to create a plan, the amount must be fixed with a unique plan id.

So here my code, the idea is to generate a date and use it to create a unique plan id but it doesnt work and im not sure is the best method, i read this but im lost, i dont know how to https://support.stripe.com/questions/metered-subscription-billing

Also i will use this form to include it into my wordpress with the plugin php-code-for-posts
(it's look to work find but i dont know if its the best practice and secure way, build a plugin is too complicated for me)

So here my files structure :

- ROOT
- ../Vendor/Stripe/ (instaled with composer, is it possible to install without composer?)
- ../Wordpress/config.php
- ../Wordpress/Stripepay.php
- ../Wordpress/charge.php
- ../Wordpress/charge2.php

The code is inspired from `https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/g2ufa8xr/`

i put in the code some // !! information about my problem

**config.php**

```
<?php
// require with composer install
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

$stripe = array(
  "secret_key"      => "sk_test_ your secret_key",
  "publishable_key" => "pk_test_ your publishable_key"
);

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
?>
```

**stripepay.php**

```
<?php require_once('../config.php');?>
<!-- Stripe Panel, This script only work remotely -->
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script> 
<!-- JQuery auto update CDN -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<!-- /////////////////////////////// ONE SHOT PAYMENT ///////////////////////////////// -->
<h2>One Donation</h2>
Please add any value below
<!-- Form and Charge Validation -->
<form id="payment-form" action="charge1" method="POST">
    <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" value="3000" placeholder="3,000 Minimum" min="3000" step="500.00" />
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken" name="stripeToken"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeEmail" name="stripeEmail"/>
</form>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Donate" class="strbtn">

<script type="text/javascript">
// JS Script Handle amount value and other Stripe options.
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: '< ?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>', // !! Possible to hide from HTML source view ?? 
    image: '../logo.jpg',
    token: function(token) {
        $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
        $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
        $("#payment-form").submit();
    }
  });

 $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var amount = $("#amount").val() *1; // !! normaly it's *1000 but with YEN need to apply this ??
// Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
// OPTIONAL, UNCHECK THE // TO ACTIVATE IT:
      //bitcoin: 'true',
      //alipay: 'true',
      billingAddress: 'true',
      zipcode: 'true',
      allowRememberMe: 'true',
      //stripeEmail: 'true', // !! Stripe in test mode doesn't send email confirmation, there is any way to check if it will works ??
      name: 'company name',
      description: 'company description',
      locale: 'auto', // !! on reults it show i'm from USA but i'm in Japan, is it based on navigator ? There is a way to be more accurate ??
      panelLabel: 'DONATE',
      currency: 'jpy',
      amount: amount  
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Close Checkout on page navigation
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });

//to prevent zero amount in the form, add 3000 when focus out of the field  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").delegate('#amount', 'focusout', function(){ // !! There is a better way to make the minimum amount 3000Yen ??
        if($(this).val() < 3000){
            $(this).val('3000');
        }
    });
});
</script>



<!-- /////////////////////////////// ANNUAL PAYMENT SUBSCIPTION ///////////////////////////////// -->
<h2>Annual Recurring Donations</h2>
Please add any value below
<!-- Form and Charge Validation -->
<form id="payment-form2" action="charge2" method="POST">
    <input type="number" id="amount2" name="amount" value="3000" placeholder="3,000 Minimum" min="3000" step="500.00" />
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken2" name="stripeToken"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeEmail2" name="stripeEmail"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="idplan" name="idplan"/>
</form>
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Subscription" class="strbtn">

<script type="text/javascript">
// JS Script Handle amount value and other Stripe options.
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: '<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>',
    image: '../str-gps-logo.jpg',
    token: function(token) {    
        $("#stripeToken2").val(token.id);
        $("#stripeEmail2").val(token.email);
        $("#payment-form2").submit();
    }
  });


 $('#btn2').on('click', function(e) {
    var amount = $("#amount2").val() *1;
    var plan = $("#idplan").val(Date); // !! Generate Date ID for the Plan to be a unique id value, possible to add milisecond too ??

// Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
      billingAddress: 'true',
      zipcode: 'true', // !! is it like this or zip-code: ??
      name: 'Year Plan',
      description: 'Variable Amount Year Plan',
      locale: 'auto',
      panelLabel: 'Subscribe',
      currency: 'jpy',
      amount: amount 
    });
    e.preventDefault(); 
    });

  // Close Checkout on page navigation
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });

//to prevent zero amount in the form, add 3000 when focus out of the field  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").delegate('#amount2', 'focusout', function(){
        if($(this).val() < 3000){
            $(this).val('3000');
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

**charge.php**

```
<?php
  require_once('./config.php');

// Check if the user have javascript and if the token is validated.
// !! code below needed or more simple with   $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];   ??

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $errors = array();
    if (isset($_POST['stripeToken'])) {
        $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    } else {
        $errors['token'] = 'The order cannot be processed. You have not been charged. 
                            Please confirm that you have JavaScript enabled and try again.';
    }
}

// Create the Customer: 
  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array( 
      'email' => $_POST['stripeEmail'],
      'source'  => $token
  ));

// Create the Charge:
  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => $_POST['amount'],
      'currency' => 'jpy'
  ));

  echo '<h1>Thanks for your donation ! </h1>'; // !! There is a way to show error to user and redirect to index ?

?>
```

**charge2.php**

```
<?php
  require_once('./config.php');

// Check if the user have javascript and if the token is validated.
//$token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $errors = array();
    if (isset($_POST['stripeToken'])) {
        $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    } else {
        $errors['token'] = 'The order cannot be processed. You have not been charged. 
                            Please confirm that you have JavaScript enabled and try again.';
    }
}

// TEST 1 inspired from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36075869/how-to-create-variable-subscriptions-in-stripe 

// !! Find the way to generate unique id to create the plan or any other solution for a variable amount recurent donation plan subscription

$plan = \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
        'name' => $_POST['idplan'],
        'id' => $_POST['idplan'],
        'interval' => 'day', // !! interval daily for testing purpose but the final will be in years 
        'interval_count' => '1',
        'currency' => 'jpy',
        'amount' => $_POST['amount']    
    ));

$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array( 
      'source'  => $token,
      'email' => $_POST['stripeEmail'],
      'plan'  => $_POST['idplan'],
      'description' => 'plan description'
    ));

echo '<h1>Thanks for your annual donation ! </h1>';
?>
```

I'm sure there is a way to make a cleaner way with only one charge file and less id mess but i dont know how too...

But if you can help me to solve the main problem i'll really be grateful, this code drive me crazy !

Cheers !

Comment: "I would like to hide the public key from html source if it's possible." Why? It's public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the form i use a technic to make the user to pay minimum 3000 YEN if he change the value to 0 for exemple when he focus out the input area in become 3000 again that's why i use value="3000" but it will be nicer if it can be only placeholder="3,000 YEN Minimum"

It's up to you to enforce this. I recommend you add both client-side (Javascript) and server-side (PHP) checks to make sure the amount is above your minimum.

> After charge user Stripe doesn't send email confirmation, i read it doesnt do it in test mode, still true ?

Yes, Stripe does not automatically send any email receipts in test mode. You can still view a specific charge in your dashboard and click on "Send Receipt" to manually send a receipt.

> I would like to hide the public key from html source if it's possible

That's not possible, but it's not a problem. The publishable key is meant to be publicly visible. It can only be used to create tokens with [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js), and tokens by themselves do nothing.

> The main problem is when user enter a variable amount and validate the form it launch the Stripe lightbox windows then it launch the charge2.php on my server but to create a plan, the amount must be fixed with a unique plan id.

There are a couple of ways to handle variable amount subscriptions. The simplest is probably to create a base plan with `amount=1`. Then, when you [create subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) to this plan, you'd use the [`quantity`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription-quantity) parameter to make sure the correct amount is billed.

A more elegant but slightly more complex solution is to create a new plan for each of your customers. In this case, you need to ensure that each plan has a unique ID -- you could for instance use the customer's email address:

```
$plan_id = "plan_" . $_POST["stripeEmail"];

$plan = \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
    "id" => $plan_id,
    "name" => "Subscription plan for " . $_POST["stripeEmail"],
    "amount" => $_POST["amount"], // amount sent by the customer's browser
    "currency" => "jpy",
    "interval" => "day",
));

$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    "email" => $_POST["stripeEmail"],
    "source" => $_POST["stripeToken"], // token returned by Stripe.js/Checkout
    "plan" => $plan_id,
));
```

In practice, all calls to Stripe's API should be wrapped in `try/catch` blocks to make sure [errors are handled](https://stripe.com/docs/api#handling-errors) correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much Ywain !